# Trying to detect which html tags are affecting an element in a string

Tags: c#, html, string, markup

I am trying to write a markup editor in c#, part of is is to detect which tags are affecting where the caret currently is.
Examples:

```
<b>Tes|ting</b><u><i>Testing</i>Testing</u> (caret '|' at index 6)
Answer: [b]

<b>Testing<u><i>Test|ing</i>Tes</b>ting</u> (caret '|' at index 20)
Answer: [b, u, i]
```

Here is the code I have currently, inside "GetTags()" I split the string into 2 queues representing what tags are in front and behind where the caret is. I played around with ways to pop the elements from both queues to try to solve the problem but I keep getting wrong results. I think im on the right track creating 2 data structures but I don't know if Queue<> is what I need.

```
public class Tag
{
    public enum TagType
    {
        bold,
        italic,
        underline,
    }

    public TagType type;
    public bool opening;

    public Tag(TagType type, bool opening)
    {
        this.type = type;
        this.opening = opening;
    }

    public static Tag GetTagFromString(string str)
    {
        switch (str)
        {
            case "<b>": return new Tag(TagType.bold, true);
            case "</b>": return new Tag(TagType.bold, false);
            case "<i>": return new Tag(TagType.italic, true);
            case "</i>": return new Tag(TagType.italic, false);
            case "<u>": return new Tag(TagType.underline, true);
            case "</u>": return new Tag(TagType.underline, false);
        }

        return null;
    }

    public static List<TagType> GetTags(string str, int index)
    {
        Queue<Tag> backQueue = new Queue<Tag>();
        Queue<Tag> forwardQueue = new Queue<Tag>();

        // populate the back queue
        int i = index;
        while (true)
        {
            int lastOpening = str.LastIndexOf('<', i);
            int lastClosing = str.LastIndexOf('>', i);

            if (lastOpening != -1 && lastClosing != -1)
            {
                string tagStr = str.Substring(lastOpening, lastClosing - lastOpening + 1);
                Tag tag = GetTagFromString(tagStr);

                backQueue.Enqueue(tag);

                i = lastOpening - 1;
                if (i < 0)
                    break;
            }
            else
                break;
        }

        // populate the front stack
        i = index;
        while (true)
        {
            int nextOpening = str.IndexOf('<', i);
            int nextClosing = str.IndexOf('>', i);

            if (nextOpening != -1 && nextClosing != -1)
            {
                string tagStr = str.Substring(nextOpening, nextClosing - nextOpening + 1);
                Tag tag = GetTagFromString(tagStr);

                forwardQueue.Enqueue(tag);

                i = nextClosing + 1;
            }
            else
                break;
        }

        List<TagType> tags = new List<TagType>();

        // populate 'tags' list with the tags affecting the index here

        return tags;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        string str = "<";
        if (!opening)
            str += "/";

        switch (type)
        {
            case TagType.bold:
                str += "b";
                break;
            case TagType.italic:
                str += "i";
                break;
            case TagType.underline:
                str += "u";
                break;
        }

        str += ">";

        return str;
    }
}
```

Would love any input on how I could solve this and would greatly appreciate any issues anyone has with the code that I've provided.

Comment: WYSIWYG Html editing is never a great idea. https://medium.engineering/why-contenteditable-is-terrible-122d8a40e480 IMHO define your own simple DOM and output html.

Comment: a few comments:
in queue you put a null (some cases),
the second example has wrong tag nesting,
watch out for tags with spaces,
what if the user has a tag inside the text